# Rails : Using local variable for an image path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, helper

I have a simple cms, and basically I have a detailed view of sauces which has an image.
In the database table I have the pictures' URL stored.
When I want to display the image, and put the variable where the image_tag url should go, the program throws an error. How do I do this?

> ```
> <tr>
>   <th>Picture</th>
>   <td><%= image_tag("sauces/sauces_piri.png") %></td>
> </tr>
> ```

thats the URL put in manually which works. The EXACT same string is stored in the database in a field called pic_url.
I already have a variable which stores the sauce object. How do I put the sauce field, instead of the direct URL.

I have tried

> ```
> <tr>
>   <th>Picture</th>
>   <td><%= image_tag("#{sauce.pic_url}") %></td>
> </tr>
> ```

This does not work

Comment: What is generated in the html on client side from the second approach?

Comment: Iv'e fixed the issue now, thank you.

Comment: Can you share how you fixed the issue?

Comment: I have answered the question. It was pretty simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I basically resolved the issue. The problem was that the sauces is an instance variable not a standard variable. 
Because I was not using the `@` sign before the sauce it was not recognising the variable.

So the correct code is as follows :

> ```
>  <td><%= image_tag("#{@sauce.pic_url}") %></td>
> ```

Hope this helps